# Is there a way to find out what called onDestroy for my Activity?

Tags: android

My Activity keeps dying unpredictably. Is there a way to find out what called onDestroy for my Activity? There's nothing in the stack if I debug, just handling of the message... Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean "unpredictably" what are you doing when the activity got destroyed? are you currently in it, in another activity? not in the app at all?

Comment: Add logcat of your project in your question.

Comment: @tyczj It goes onPause while Authenticator shows its 'collect credentials' Activity. There's Login with Facebook button in the authenticator activity which initiates Facebook login. While logging into Facebook, the first activity (that triggered the authenticator) gets destroyed. First I thought maybe Facebook was killing it somehow, but now that I couldn't reproduce it in a simple project, something else might be going on... Ideally I'd like to know where's this onDestroy is called so I want to trace it if possible..

Comment: @Md.NasirUddinBhuiyan if there was something useful in the logs I wouldn't be asking this queston...

Comment: more than likely its the OS killing the activity because it needs to reclain resources

Comment: @tyczj I would accept that if it was one time only thing - happens every time, on different devices.

Comment: you can use Thread#getStackTrace() but i am still not sure if that is what you really need

Comment: read the docs for on destroy http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy() activity gets destroyed by calling `finish()` or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the `isFinishing()` method. so if `isFinishing()` is false then its the OS

Comment: @tyczj when the OS wants to reclaim some memory most likely onDestroy will not be called,  only onPause is guaranteed to be called

Comment: @pskink not according to the documentation

Comment: @tyczj ok, read the docs again, put in a few logs - `onDestroy()` gets called and `isFinishing()` returns true, which, as I understood, means activity's `finish()` was called. However, my breakpoint in `finish()` call was not hit. Thoughts?

Comment: @vkislicins without looking at your code i have no idea

Comment: @tyczj "Because onPause() is the first of the three, once the activity is created, onPause() is the last method that's guaranteed to be called before the process can be killed—if the system must recover memory in an emergency, then onStop() and onDestroy() might not be called" http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html also see "Killable after?" column, also Activity#onDestroy docs say " There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it should not be used to do things that are ..."

Comment: I found the root cause of the problem - there was a noHistory flag on the activity in the manifest. Still doesn't explain why `finish()` call did not log anything.

Answer (score -1):

You can use logs and just place them in certain places in your code. Then just monitor the logcat to see what comes up

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: I have plenty of logs - it's not helping. Plus there is still a possibility that onDestroy comes from a) system b) other process

Comment: _You can use calls to the logging API's and just place them in certain places in your code. Then just monitor the LogCat to see what comes up._ That is how it should be.